# Opencv program using qtcreator undefined reference in ubuntu for imread or any string

Tags: qt-creator, opencv3.0, undefined-reference, imread

```cpp
include "mainwindow.h"
include "ui_mainwindow.h"
include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread("/home/chaiein/VR/1.jpg");
    cv::imshow("Display Image", inputImage);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Error 
/home/chaiein/VR/linePose/mainwindow.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, int)'

My linepose.pro file as the following content

```
    QT       += core gui
    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
    TARGET = linePose
    TEMPLATE = app
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-
     3.2.0-dev
     LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui
     SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
     HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
     FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I have searched in many links but this problem seems to have different solution please help me!!